# returning string along with List data in Json as output

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a controller method accepting two parameters. This method is used to retrieve a particular row of data corresponding to the ID which is passed via parameter. I have to send the another parameter in the return type value along with the retrieved data. How can I do that?

```
public JsonResult  GetById(int? id, string message)  
{
    var data = (from z in db.ProdModels 
                where z.FirmId == id
                select z).ToList();
    //data.Add();
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I have to return `string message` with the `JSON returned data`. Is it possible? Is there any way of returning the string along with the `Json` data?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return new JsonResult( new {data=data, message=message});
```

or I usually prefer

```
public ActionResult  GetById(int? id, string message)  
{
    if(id==null) return BadRequest();

    var data = (from z in db.ProdModels 
                where z.FirmId == id
                select z).ToList();
    return Ok( new {data=data, message=message} );
    
}
```

or if you using an old Mvc version

```
 var result= new 
  {
            Message = message,
            Data = data
   };
 return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: What does it mean by `return Ok` and I think we have to use `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` as my requirement.